Who are the enslaved mutants shown working as laborers in Cable's dark future timeline in X-Men '97?
In the X-Men '97 episode "Tolerance Is Extinction - Part 1" (Season 1, Episode 8), Cable gives us a glimpse into his dark future timeline. He reveals that in his timeline, Bastion started an all-out war between humans and mutants, and any mutant who managed to survive was essentially enslaved and forced into labor. 
The episode shows a scene of several mutants working as slave laborers:

A red-haired female mutant shooting energy beams from her hands

A blonde-haired male mutant sporting a red headband, with arms that morph into metal, reminiscent of Colossus' abilities, though he bears no resemblance to him


A green-haired female mutant shooting circular green energy waves (I'm guessing Polaris)


A red-haired telekinetic female mutant with white eyes, black facial stripes, and the ability to envelope objects in a fiery aura and control them
 


Can anyone shed light on the identities of these mutants?

The style of drawing of that first girl greatly reminds me of someone, but I can't for the life of me remember who it is I'm thinking about

The girl reminds me (off-topic and not a serious answer) of Poochie from The Simpsons. Or April O'Neil from TMNT.

#4 looks very much like it must be a Hound, Rachel Summers/Prestige.

Absolutely agree with #3 being an older Polaris, color scheme and power set match up.
I can't speculate to the blonde with the metal arms or the redhead with generic energy projection. Either of them could be several different mutants we've seen through the decades in the comics.

Thanks! I've added an image of Rachel Summers as a Hound to your post. If you know of a better image to include instead, please [edit] it into your post.

The mutants they show as enslaved are Easter eggs from the original animated series season one episode eleven  “Days of Future Past Part I”.  These were entire cut from whole cloth as mobs that future Wolverine saves from sentinels.
Still shot from "Days of Future Past Part 1"



Speculation: A new, unrevealed character not existing in current
continuity. Related to Jubilee in some way, as she has pink
energy and pink clothing with a yellow short-sleeve jacket.


Speculation: A new, unrevealed character not existing in current continuity. Forge is known for wearing a red headband, and Magik (Ilyana Rasputin, Colossus' sister) is blonde, so maybe a child of Magik with a relationship to Forge?



An older Polaris (Lorna Dane), who has a green costume and hair and magnetic powers.


Rachel Summers/Askani as Phoenix in Excalibur is red-haired, has a fiery aura, and has an Ahab's Hound face in the Days of Future Present storyline.




This answer doesn't contribute much to the thread. A prior answer already IDed character 4 as Rachel Summers, and you didn't add much in the way of further evidence. The OP already guessed that character 3 is Polaris, and again, you didn't didn't add much in the way of further evidence. The rest of your answer is pure speculation, with no attempt made to actually name the characters you were referring to.

That's because I believe characters 1 and 2 don't exist in the current Marvel universe. They're new. There's no other way to answer to their identities other than speculation, and the new information I provided matches with their appearances and existing characters.

Characters 1 and 2 may not have appeared before, but we tend to discourage users from posting answers based on nothing but guesswork. That said, I'd be more accepting of it if it wasn't such tenuous guesswork. Arguing that character 2 might be related to Forge because they both wear headbands is rather silly in my opinion. Your argument in regard to character 1 being related to Jubilee isn't much better (Jubilee is of Chinese descent and unlikely to have a redhead as a relative). You have added value to your answer by editing in images of Polaris and Rachel Summers, so props for that.

1 and 2. have appeared in the cartoon before (the original series, not 97). But they were not named there either. They were the two random mutants in Bishop's first appearance.

@suchiuomizu That's interesting. I think it may be worth adding that information as a new answer.

@LogicDictates, your opinion that something is silly doesn't seem to add much value to the discussion. Counter the speculation with your own conjecture using information, not gut feelings. Hair color has very little to do with ethnicity, people of any background can change their hair color to whatever they want even without mutant powers.

@Michael Caprio - You're comparing apples with oranges. We're much more accepting of opinions when they're posted as comments rather than as answers. The two things serve very different functions, and it's significantly harder to corroborate views expressed as comments with evidence and reasoning due to the strict character limit on them, and the fact that the site itself discourages users from having extended discussions within the comments section. I am willing to go into a more detailed discussion with you if you like, but the site will instruct us to take it to a chatroom at some point.

It's possible that the blonde male with metal arms is some variant iteration of Pavel Rasputin link, the red headband is sort of evocative of Pavel's red hood that he likes to wear. But it's pure speculation.

@LogicDictates, you didn't address any of my points in my response, so I'll take that to mean that you don't disagree with me on hair color. I don't care to take anything to a chatroom, and I don't see why I have to follow whatever you tell me to do on the site with regard to my contributions.

The second resembles Franklin Richards from Days of the Future Present, and he was represented as being capable of changing his arms in that way in that future. 

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This would be better if you could find a picture with the arms to show that matches.

All of the mutants in the camps in that run wore green jumpsuits with an "M" on the left breast, but that sleeveless long jacket in OP's screenshot does not look like a jumpsuit. I don't remember exactly what Franklin's powers were in this alternate reality, I just remember that his codename was "Scrapper" and he had energy manipulation. I'm not convinced that this is Franklin, and I think @nestor-sanchez in another answer got it correctly. Both are lifted directly from the original animated series and were probably throwaway characters at the time.
